# RSpec Helper Parameters Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test the following code:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def current_book
    Book.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

using the following test with RSpec:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, :type => :helper do
  describe "#current_book" do
    book_1 = create(:book)

    params = {}
    params[:id] = book_1.id

    expect(helper.current_book).to eq(book_1)
  end
end
```

But for some reason the params[:id] parameter isn't being passed in properly. Any suggestions with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stub the params:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationHelper, type: :helper do
  describe "#current_book" do
    let(:first_book) { create(:book) }

    before(:all) { helper.stub!(:params).and_return(id: 1) }

    it "returns a book with a matching id" do
      expect(helper.current_book).to eq(first_book)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where would I put this line?

Comment: I extended the answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Please explain why stubs are needed.

Comment: In the given example the `params` variable was declared inside the block, but it is not the same `params` variable, which is set in the helper instance. Therefor we must stub the `params` variable on the helper instance, which we are testing

Comment: Getting an error: undefined method `view_context' for nil:NilClass

Comment: nvm. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here another way of stubbing params. I think this requires rspec 3 can't remember for sure.

```
context 'path is a route method' do
  before { allow(helper).to receive(:params).and_return(order_by: { updated_at: :desc }) }
  subject { helper.sortable_link_to('Created At', order_by: :created_at) }
  it { is_expected.to match /comments/ }
  it { is_expected.to match /\?order_by/}
  it { is_expected.to match /\?order_by%5Bupdated_at%5D=asc/}
end
```